# Find a range inside a range using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I've a date list

StartDate            EndDate

```
1-Nov-2011         31-Jan-2012   
3-Mar-2012          1-Apr-2012  
1-May-2012         31-Dec-2012 
1-Jan-2013          1-Dec-2013
```

Get all the records which falls in this range

```
1-Jan-2012          31-Dec-2012
```

The answer would be the first three records from the above list

How could i do it using Linq.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have tried? Also, what is the structures you are storing the values in? Classes/Lists/KeyValueParis/Tuples?

Comment: @astander  I am using List<DateTime>.

Comment: So 2 seperate List<DateTime>, one for StartDate and another for EndDate?

Comment: @astander Actually no, i have List<CustomObject>, that have properties StartDate and EndDate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var rangeStart = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
var rangeEnd = new DateTime(2012, 12, 31);
var res = list
    .Where(item => (item.StartTime < rangeStart ? rangeStart : item.StartTime) < (item.EndTime < rangeEnd ? item.EndTime : rangeEnd) )
    .ToList();
```

The condition is "the larger of the two left ends needs to be less than the smaller of the two right ends".

Comment: It took me couple of minutes to test the answer and a whole hour to figure out what is going on and believe on it, a word WOW comes out and lot of appreciation with a BIG THANKS.

Comment: @MegaMind You are welcome! This is a very useful trick in general, when it comes to intervals. Note that if you calculate `max(start1,start2)-min(end1, end2)`, and get a positive number, that's the amount of overlap between the intervals; if you get a negative number, that's the gap between the intervals.

Answer (score 2):

I Suggest the following wrapper

```
public struct DateInterval
    {
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public bool HasIntersection(DateInterval secondInterval)
        {
            return HasIntersection(this.StartDate, this.EndDate,secondInterval.StartDate,secondInterval.EndDate);
        }
        private bool HasIntersection(DateTime dateStart1, DateTime dateEnd1, DateTime dateStart2, DateTime dateEnd2)
        {
            if (dateEnd1 < dateStart2) return false; 
            if (dateEnd2 < dateStart1) return false; 
            return true;
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
        var targetInterval = new DateInterval() {StartDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1), EndDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1)};
        var listOfIntervals =GetIntervals();//retrieve data
        var filteredList = listOfIntervals.Where(targetInterval.HasIntersection).ToList();
```